# Setting editor.fontsize for multiple folders in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Because of the flexibility and continuous improvements on `vs code`, I thought it was time to test it out and to compare it to the standard editor `PowerShell ISE`. However, I'm running into the following issue:

When opening a folder I can see in the explorer pane on the left of `vs code` that this folder contains files. When I then add another folder with the option `File` > `Add Folder to Workspace`, two folders become visible on the left, which is normal. However, when I want to set the font size of the editor to `"editor.fontSize": 13`, it's only applied to one side of the viewing pane. I have two open files, `File1` is opened from `Folder1` and `File2` is opened from `Folder2`.

The problem is that only `File1` is changing its font size, but `File2` does not.

**How do I set the font size?**

- CTRL + SHFT + P
- Preference: Open workspace settings

**settings.json**

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite default and user settings.
{
     "editor.wordWrap": "on",
      "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
      "editor.fontSize": 13
}
```

How is it possible to have the same font size applied to both files in the split window?

**Workaround**

The only workaround I found is copying the file `settings.json` from `Folder1` to `Folder2` and end up with two `settings.json` files.

Opened an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/30375) for this.

Version: 1.14.0-insider

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly I think there are a couple of ways to accomplish this:

1) Add `"editor.fontSize": 13` to your user settings instead of your workspace settings.

2) Make sure your `.vscode` directory with the `settings.json` file is at the highest level in your project.  See screen grab below.

[image]

Both of these options worked for me.

Comment: It appears to be a bug that needs fixing. see [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/30375).

Comment: If you add `"editor.fontSize": 13` to your user settings then the font size will be applied globally across all instances of VSCode.  Would that not accomplish what you're looking for?

Comment: What you say is correct. but not when you work with multiple folders. I'm using the insider version which has this feature added. Really cool, but the settings.json file isn't applied in both folders unless you create one for each folder separately.